# check network speed by sending 1GB file from one set of serves to another set of servers remotely

Tags: linux, shell

I want to test network speed by sending 1GB file from one set of serves to another set of servers remotely

Ex:

s1 -> s11
s2 -> s21
s3 -> s31

currently I am in my local machine(LM) and I need to loginto server s1 and create random 1G file and scp to server:s11 and like wise s2 to s21 and so on..
testing with one set  as below

```
ssh $1 <<EOD
dd if=/dev/zero of=file_test count=1024 bs=1048576
scp file_test $2:/tmp
EOD
```

It works great, but its not proving the scp data transmission speed/sec, when I do on it in LM it does.

```
scp file_test server1:/tmp
file_test                                          100% 1024MB 113.8MB/s  00:09
```

I want to print the those stats as well while running through the shell script.How to achieve this from script , I need to do the same thing and collect results for 100+ serers

Comment: Two things... your result will not be correct unless your disk is considerably faster than your network - think how long it would take to transfer a file across a 1Gbit/s network from a 5Mbit/s disk. You should read the data straight from `/dev/zero` not from disk. Secondly, `ssh` encrypts data which will slow down the transfer so your speed will not be correct because of that too - maybe use `netcat` rather than `ssh`. If you don't believe me, try a less secure, but faster protocol for `ssh` and measure the speed.

Comment: Secondly, you can measure the time taken to do the transfer and you know the filesisze, so you don't really need `dd` to tell you the transfer rate, it is just `volume of data/time taken`

Comment: Thank you for your time,in my corporation network I don't have netcat command.

Comment: Giving ssh the `-t` option may help.

Answer (score 0):

`scp` does not have an option to show the statistics when run non-interactively. You can try with `rsync`

```
ssh $1 <<EOD
dd if=/dev/random of=file_test count=1024 bs=1048576
rsync file_test $2:/tmp
EOD
```

With `/dev/random` you will get a random file (otherwise you will have a 0-filled file which can be easily compressed).

Comment: Even rsync also not showing the network statistics, and when I run the /dev/random not generating the 1G file with above dd option.